# Sails.JS - Server to Server communication using socket.io

Tags: socket.io, sails.js, server-to-server

I have an architecture having a central Sails.JS (let's call it A) and multiple Sails.JS that gets/sends info from A (it will be called B).

I need to make a link between A and B using sockets.

Any idea howto do that ?

Comment: You can use [Socket.io](http://socket.io) and [sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js) on the server just like you can use them on the client.  Give it a try, and come back to SO if you have specific questions!